# PHP: Get minimum number from string separated by commas

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using min() to get the lowest number from a string I have - I've converted the string to an array for min() but it doesn't output anything.

```
$empty_room_id .= '2, 3, 4, ';
$empty_room_id_array = explode(", ",$empty_room_id);

echo 'Lowest number: ' . min($empty_room_id_array) . '<br />';
echo 'All numbers: ' . $empty_room_id . '<br />';
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Appreciate any help!

Comment: $empty_room_id in not an array. explode works in case of array

Comment: @MahaDev That's incorrect. It shows nothing because the array made with explode contains a space aswell. Change `$empty_room_id .= '2, 3, 4, ';` to `$empty_room_id .= '2, 3, 4';`

Comment: @Daan thanks for correcting me

Comment: Not a space but an empty element. Use `var_dump($empty_room_id_array);` to see the actual result of the explode().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the 4 you have empty space: that's the lowest value. You'd better remoe all empty space from your string before exploding it. So you want this:

```
$empty_room_id .= explode(", ",str_replace(' ','','2, 3, 4'));
```

if you got that string automatically and can't remove the last nasty ',' and useless spaces, you can do this:

```
$empty_room_id = preg_replace(array('/ /','/,$/'),array('',''), $empty_room_id);
$empty_room_id_array = explode(",",$empty_room_id);
```

or, since we're already messing with regexes:

```
preg_match('/\d+?/', $empty_room_id, $empty_room_id_array);
```

Comment: Ah I didn't realize it counted empty spaces! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Actually it isn't even counting the white space, but the null value after the last comma...

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

```
// Create string
$string = '2, 3, 4, 5, 6';

// Explode string to convert it to an array
$workArray = explode(',', $string);

// Sort array by numeric values
$sorted = sort($workArray);

// Get lowest number
$lowestValue = current($sorted);
```

#### Edit

You can also do:

```
$lowest = min($workArray);
```

Comment: One question, why is this better?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your array contains an empty string (the last element), if you remove those instances (and only keep the numbers), you will get the expected behaviour. There are multiple approaches, but heres a quick one:

```
echo 'Lowest number: ' . min(array_filter($empty_room_id_array)) . '<br />';
```

Note that this will also remove zeroes, so maybe not optimal depending on you number ranges